# RE: 0000208F error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

we are having problems with DNS whereas when a statically assigned system is rebooted it loses its connection to DNS, browsing through the logs for the issue, I have found the following:

The DNS server was unable to complete directory service enumeration of zone grh.com.  This DNS server is configured to use information obtained from Active Directory for this zone and is unable to load the zone without it.  Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly and repeat enumeration of the zone. The extended error debug information (which may be empty) is "0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001F7, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:

```
'DC=**][';phjya**,DC=xxx.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=xxx,DC=com'"
```

This showed up this morning on renumeration on our 2008R2 SOA.  I looked through ADSIEdit and do not find it, where could this be coming from?

I believe this  "][';phjya"   is part of the issue.

After running dcdiag checking DNS on the server itself believe my issue lies in the AD's DNS application directory, ooooh crap if I have to rebuild that...